# WinRT XAML Toolkit for Windows Phone 8

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I just wanted to know that is there any control like treeview in WinRT XAML Toolkit for WindowsPhone 8.0

Comment: Check out Windows Phone Toolkit: Get it using NuGet or their website here: https://phone.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

The TreeView doesn't conform to the design UI pattern used by the phone. You should rethink the UI so it won't require a treeview. (e.g. have a look at LongListSelector).

(... if you really must though there are some implementations like [this one](https://treeviewwp8.codeplex.com/))